# Removing '#include <algorithm>' doesn't break the code

Tags: c++, algorithm

Maybe this is a very silly question, but the book I'm reading instructed me to write a piece of code that uses algorithms to scramble and order the elements in a vector. To do this the book tells me to use the algorithms library from the main C++ library. Alright, so far I understand it, but after writing the code I wanted to see what would break if I would remove this library from the top-part of my code, and it surprised me that everything still worked.

This is the code I'm talking about. When I remove '#include algorithm' from the top-part of the code, nothing breaks. How can this be? Isn't the 'random_shuffle' part supposed to break when not using this library?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int>::const_iterator iter;

    cout << "Creating a list of scores.";
    vector<int> scores;
    scores.push_back(1500);
    scores.push_back(3500);
    scores.push_back(7500);

    cout << "\nHigh Scores:\n";
    for (iter = scores.begin(); iter != scores.end(); ++iter)
    {
        cout << *iter << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nFinding a score.";
    int score;
    cout << "\nEnter a score to find: ";
    cin >> score;
    iter = find(scores.begin(), scores.end(), score);
    if (iter != scores.end())
    {
        cout << "Score found.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Score not found.\n";
    }

    cout << "\nRandomizing scores.";
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    random_shuffle(scores.begin(), scores.end());
    cout << "\nHigh Scores:\n";
    for (iter = scores.begin(); iter != scores.end(); ++iter)
    {
        cout << *iter << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nSorting scores.";
    sort(scores.begin(), scores.end());
    cout << "\nHigh Scores:\n";
    for (iter = scores.begin(); iter != scores.end(); ++iter)
    {
        cout << *iter << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: which compiler? if I remove `#include <algorithm>` in VS2010 it fails to compile.

Comment: I'm using NetBeans IDE 7.1 and MinGW.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason it works is because  has been included by a header that you have also included.

For example vector might have included algorithms in it's source. This is common as they are often header only.

That said, you can not rely on the specific implementation of the standard library to have the same includes in each header. (for example with might work with MSVC and it might break with gcc stdlibc+++).

For this reasons I highly recommend including what you use, regardless of where it will compile of not. --- note that this is slightly different to 'what you reference' because forward declaration for point and references in headers can significantly improve build time.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard does not dictate which headers are included by each standard header. This means that for example, `<vector>` might `#include <algorithm>` for library implementation A, but not in library implementation B. This might also change between different releases of the same library or on different ports of it. glibc++ for example once cleaned up their include hierarchies significantly.

This puts us C++ programmers in some miscomfort as we should make sure to include the correct ones, even though some standard header already did so; if we are lazy, we risk that compilation breaks on other platforms, system up- and downgrades.

Rule of thumb:

> Include what is necessary as per the header's definition. But not more.

"But not more", because compilation times can become unecessarily slow.

Comment: _"we risk that compilation breaks on other platforms"_ or when you write `apt-get upgrade gcc`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: This is included in my own, very abstract and highly strict definition of the term "platform". After an upgrade, it's another platform than before. But I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: @phresnel: Fair enough. The difference being that you should upgrade every week (well maybe not your toolchain, but your environment in general needs updates for security etc) but you're unlikely to switch deployment platforms too often (so "another platform" turns into a pure portability problem).

Answer (score 1):

The code works because vector includes algorithm internally.
To verify what is included and what is not, you can generate the pre processor output by passing the -E flag to the compiler.

Write a sample file: temp.C which has just a single line:

```
#include <vector>
```

Now, if we compile the file as `g++ -E temp.C`, you will be able to see in the output that algorithm is included.

Comment: Upvote from me, but I think it is easier though to see that algorithm is included (like it is for me) with g++ temp.cpp -M

Comment: Note that it depends on the library implementation; you can't rely on `<vector>` including `<algorithm>` or anything else (and indeed, on my particular implementation, it doesn't).

Comment: Good suggestion with the -E flag, however, it does not answer "How can that be?"

Comment: Nice one. Have never used -M before

Answer (score 0):

Breaks here

```
janus@Zeus:~$ g++ test.cpp 
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:27:52: error: no matching function for call to ‘find(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator, int&)’
test.cpp:27:52: note: candidate is:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:359:5: note: template<class _CharT2> typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<_CharT2>::__value, std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT2, std::char_traits<_CharT> > >::__type std::find(std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT2, std::char_traits<_CharT> >, std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT2, std::char_traits<_CharT> >, const _CharT2&)
test.cpp:39:48: error: ‘random_shuffle’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:47:38: error: ‘sort’ was not declared in this scope
janus@Zeus:~$
```

gcc 4.6.1

Comment: Not here, maybe you are using a different IDE?

Comment: Not an answer to "How can this be?"

Comment: @phresnel if the presumption doesn't hold, it makes no sense to answer how it can be. Maybe OP was using weird compiler flags. I maintain that seeing how a different compiler gives him a different result may answer some questions like how it is not dictated by the standard which headers your headers include.

Answer (score 0):

The code does not compile for me when i removed the #include algorithms line. At the risk of sounding very patronising are you sure you've recompiled?

My compiler output:

```
a.cpp(28) : error C3861: 'find': identifier not found
a.cpp(40) : error C3861: 'random_shuffle': identifier not found
a.cpp(48) : error C3861: 'sort': identifier not found
```

Comment: I'm very sure. I'm using NetBeans by the way, maybe it's a difference in our IDE's?

Comment: I'm just using command line. Its been a while since i used netbeans, but as i remember back then you had to right click the class in the project browser and click recompile. (@phresnel: I think it is a politely phrased possible answer to how this could be. He could have not known that includes needed to be recompiled)

Comment: Whoops, I judged in an accident, I was really about to post my comment somehwere else, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, standard headers are allowed to include other standard headers, so there's no guarantee that your code will break if you forget one.

Answer (score 0):

The `#include` preprocessor directive doesn't "include" a library in the linking process, just instructs the precompiler to read a header file and include it in the source file it is compiling as a single unit.

That said, the `algorithm` header file might be included by another include file.

Note: A particular function or method may be declared and **defined** in a header file, so it doesn't need linking.

edit:
Your code is well written and should work as expected. I would only advice you to use the newline predefined character `endl` and to include it at the end of an output sequence, not at the beginning of the next:

```
cout << "Creating a list of scores." << endl;  
cout << "High Scores:" << endl;
```